# String format does not consider spaces in the string

Tags: c#, string-formatting

Updated the question for better understanding. This is just the snippet of the entire code. It has been modified to focus the problem.

I have a MVC application, a view is being populated based on the database entries.

I am looping through the model entries and populating the labels and image with data stored in database.

Example:

```
foreach (var item in Model)
{
   <img src=@String.Format("../Uploads/Gallery/Image/{0}", item.fileName) style="border: none;width: 100%;">
   <label>@item.fileName</label>
}
```

And the model entries are:

```
test.png
test (1).png
```

The image source is not set as expected and the image is not displayed for the second entry ie. `test (1).png`

The element looks like this:

```
<img src="../Uploads/Gallery/Image/test" (1).png="">
```

The desired output is

```
<img src="../Uploads/Gallery/Image/test (1).png">
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean the result of the string formatting won't include any quotes at all. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I get the required output - so there must be something else wrong somewhere.

Comment: You mean you get a string, in which a part of the string isn't even in the string?

Comment: I suspect the string format is working fine, but that the part of your application that uses the formatted URI can't deal with spaces. To fix, you should probably apply some URL encoding (e.g. replace spaces with %20). This can be done using `HttpUtlity` `UrlEncode` function https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I have update the question for better understanding. Please take a look.

Comment: You need quotes: `<img src="@string.Format("../Uploads/Gallery/Image/{0}", item.fileName)" style="…"`

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed by @poke I had to add quote:

`<img src="@string.Format("../Uploads/Gallery/Image/{0}", item.fileName)">`